# How many circles pass through 2 points but also tangent to a given circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Given: a circle $O$. and $2$ points $A, B$ out of that circle.

How many new circles that are tangent to circle $O$ can we form which also pass through points $A,B$.

My Geometry is a somewhat rusty - I find hard time solving this because I am missing the new circle as there could be virtually infinite circles (with different radii and centers)  that pass through 3 points ($A$, $B$, another point on circle $O$) - how do I know how many of them are tangent? My guess is only $2$ but I can't show it. I understand that this forum demands one to show effort, but really I have nothing to write here. Any help would be appreciated.

**edit:** I understand that in some settings the answer is $0$. so let's add a new condition that the points $A,B$ are both below the circle $O$. so the line between them does not reach the given circle.

Comment: Just on a side note, this can be solved nicely using inversion (with inversion center the center of the given circle).

Comment: There are solutions if A and B are both in the exterior while parts of the line between them cross the circle. The real condition for a solution is not having one point in the interior and the other in the exterior.

Comment: @OscarLanzi, yes, I think you are right. the new circle will include there the given circle. thanks for your remark.

Comment: @Zuy, thanks for the lead. unfortunately I have never heard of "inversions" before. I might try to learn about this tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: # of tangent circles thru two points outside a given circle]

Given a circle with radius $CE$ and two points $A$, $B$ outside the circle.

Join $AB$ and set up the perpendicular bisector at $D$.

On this line lie the centers of all circles passing through $A$, $B$,
and from each of these points lines can be drawn: to $A$, and through center $C$ to the opposite side of the given circle (or to center $C$ through the near side).

Let $F$ be the (unique) point on the perpendicular bisector such that$$FA=FCE$$The circle drawn with center $F$ and radius $FA$ is internally tangent to the given circle, since common point $E$ lies on the line through their centers but not between them.

Next let $G$ be the (unique) point equidistant from $A$ and point $H$ on the near side of the given circle. The circle with center $G$ and radius $GA$ is externally tangent to the given circle since now $H$ lies on the line through their centers and between them.

I have not shown how to construct points $F$ and $G$, but if it's clear that these points on the perpendicular bisector exist, then two and only two circles pass through points $A$, $B$ tangent to the given circle, one internally and one externally.

Comment: Very elegant, thanks. though for some reason I find it hard to seize like I'm missing an anchor here. It sounds odd, but why there is far and near sides? why there is no "middle size" (I mean the answer could have only the near side and say we have 1 tangent circle -and I would miss the far side). Also it might show that the number of circles is not higher than 2, but I'm not sure 100% it shows that those circle indeed exist because it seems $H$ and $E$ were given then it says they lie on the line between the centers. But despite all that which still not sits well in my mind, it is convincing.

Comment: My argument is not as clear and complete as I would like, and I’ve tried some small edits. I think the role of the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ is key, and the continuously changing lengths of $FA$ and $FCE$ as we move point $F$ up and down the line, and similarly of $GA$ and $GH$ as we move point $G$.  GeoGebra helps make this clear, and although I don’t have an actual construction for making $FA=FCE$, it seems such a position of $F$ (and $G$) must exist. $E$ and $H$ are not given; they are where $FC$ and $GC$ cross the given circle when $F$ and $G$ are such as to make $FA=FCE$ and $GA=GH$.

Comment: Ah, I see it clearer now. the tentative $F$ (or $G$) are moving, till the line $FC$ cuts the given circle in a point $E$ where $FE=AF$. Now, there are only 2 options because the line $FC$ cuts the given circle on two points. so for every tentative $F$ there is in theory max two possible solutions. it is clear however that only one is possible each time, if it works at all as most of tentative $F$ points won't suffice the condition of equidistant for either of the cutting points. From your explanation I can see why only one tentative $F$ is working for each "side".

Answer (score 0):

Draw a perpendicular bisector to line AB. It cuts the given circle at two points say T1 and T2 (not labeled that way in the sketch).

Then there are *two circles*, ABT1 sand ABT2 one of which makes *external* contact and the other makes *internal* contact. That is, the given circle can be placed once outside and once inside.

A straight line can be taken to be circle as special case if points A,B,T1 or A,B,T2 are collinear.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is not complete. Please note that perpendicular bisector is not bound to cut the given circle at all, hence no $T_1$ and $T_2$ points necessarly exist. Moreover, in the example given in the answer the perpendicular bisector cut the center of the given circle. If this were the case I can indeed see how the answer solves this. but say it is not the case, it is not clear to me why circles $ABT_1$  and $ABT_2$ are tangent to the given circle - it may be the case, but I'm afraid I can't see it from the answer.

Comment: You are right! It has to be maybe adapted from the Steiner Circle chain, as another solution..